# How to add different tags to all elements of a list of user-defined dataclasses, when attempting to insert the list in influxdb using one call

Tags: python, python-asyncio, influxdb, aioinflux

I'm trying to insert an whole list of user-defined dataclasses in my influxdb server, and provide different tags to each, while also using **a single write call**. I'm using aioinflux.

Is this possible?
So far, I've been looking at the `aioinflux.InfluxDBClient`'s [write](https://aioinflux.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#aioinflux.client.InfluxDBClient.write) function.

I see that there it has a `tag_columns` argument, but the docs indicate that it can only be used in tandem with dataframes. Then there is the `extra_tags` argument, but since I want to write **a list** of dataclasses using **a single** write call, the method seems rather useless in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was waylaid by how the [write](https://aioinflux.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#aioinflux.client.InfluxDBClient.write) function is structured. Basically, it seems that its `extra_tags` argument has no effect on user-defined dataclass objects.

After doing a little bit of random searching I found out [this table](https://aioinflux.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#user-defined-class-schema-type-annotations) which suggests that one can add tags to each datapoint by making the tags part of the dataclass. This way, one can insert an Iterable of dataclasses **and** make sure that they have tags.

Comment: to add on this there are examples of using `TAG` in the user defined class objects section as well https://aioinflux.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#writing-user-defined-class-objects